# copy assets to documents directory

Tags: ios

I am using the `ctAssetPickerController` for Picking videos and images. After the user has finished picking videos and images I want to copy them to another folder. I am using the export session and `requestAvAssetForVideo` method but the problem is it copies only one file at a time and I am not able to get the name of the file that the user is selecting, and it is copying videos only. How do I copy the images also? Below is my code.

```
- (void)assetsPickerController:(CTAssetsPickerController *)picker didFinishPickingAssets:(NSArray *)assets
{

        PHImageManager *manager = [PHImageManager defaultManager];

    [manager requestAVAssetForVideo:obj options:PHVideoRequestOptionsDeliveryModeAutomatic resultHandler:^(AVAsset * asset, AVAudioMix * _Nullable audioMix, NSDictionary * _Nullable info) {
        AVAssetExportSession *exporter = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:asset presetName:AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality];        
        NSString *imageName = @"img_o462.mp4";
        NSString *selectedFilesCopyPath = [[self getRootFolderPath] stringByAppendingString:@"/Photos"];

        if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager]fileExistsAtPath:selectedFilesCopyPath]) {
            [[NSFileManager defaultManager]createDirectoryAtPath:selectedFilesCopyPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:nil];
        }

        NSString *copyPath = [selectedFilesCopyPath stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@",imageName]];
        //            NSError *copyError= nil;

        exporter.outputURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:copyPath];
        exporter.outputFileType = AVFileTypeMPEG4;

        [exporter exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{
            // here your file will be saved into file system at specified exportUrl
            NSLog(@"file copied");

            if (exporter.status == AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted) {
                NSLog(@"success");
                [self showErrorAlert:@"Success"];
            } else {
                NSLog(@"error: %@", [exporter error]);
                [self showErrorAlert:exporter.error];
            }
        }];

    }];
}
```

Comment: can anybody please help me out here? i am stuck!